# How do I get the difference of each number in the list from other numbers?

Tags: python

For example, in a situation where I have 100 different locations, I want to find the farthest location from the others. so I thought of a for loop that would take the difference of each position from the other 99 and add it to a list. the same locations in the loop should not meet.

I thought of making a condition for it. it works but I'm not sure if it's the right approach. What approach should I take in such a situation?

```
def getDifferenceCoord(t1, t2):
    expDist = (t1[0] - t2[0]) ** 2 + (t2[1] - t1[1]) ** 2
    dist = expDist ** 0.5
    return dist


allDistance = []
for i in range(len(locationList)): 
    for j in range(len(locationList) - 1):
        if i == j:
            j = 99
        allDistance.append(getDifferenceCoord(locationList[i], locationList[j]))
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use native code to make such a function?

Comment: Could you post a sample of allDistance content and the getDifferenceCoord() function please?

Comment: If you only want to find the farthest location you don't need a separate list of all distances, all you need is to store the lowest possible distance in the beginning and in each double-loop check whether `getDifferenceCoord()` returns a farther location than that, and update that distance if it does.

Comment: You have `expDist` vs `preDist` confusion in `getDifferenceCoord`.  That code won't work.

Comment: `itertools.combinations(locationList, 2)` will give you all possible pairs of locations.

Comment: @zwer Can you explain a little more? I can find the 2 furthest points from each other, but the order in my list determines which one is the furthest point.

Comment: @vushalina can you define what you mean under 'furthest point'? I thought you meant finding the largest distance between two points (i.e. furthest point relative to another point) for which all you need to do is iterate over all of your points and calculate their distances from one another. If you want to find a furthest point from another frame of reference, you need to establish that frame first (e.g. furthest from `(0, 0)` or furthest from a common _center of mass_) and use that as a common comparison point as you iterate over your points and compare the calculated distances.

Comment: @zwer Consider 99 points clustered on the right of a space and a single point on the left. I want the point on the left. I guess I couldn't express myself well enough, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @vushalina - In that case, find first the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of your points and then find a point that's the furthest from it.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the distances:

```
from itertools import permutations
allDistance = [getDifferenceCoord(i, j) for (i, j) in permutations(locationList, 2)]
```

If the return distances are the same (which they normally would be) a more efficient method is:

```
from itertools import combinations
allDistance = [getDifferenceCoord(i, j) for (i, j) in combinations(locationList, 2)]
```

`permutations`: all `i`,`j` where `i!=j`

`combinations`: all `i`,`j` where `j>i` (half of the permutations)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right approach. There are minor optimisations that can be made for memory or processing complexity but it remains and O(N^2) problem either way.

One minor adjustment, if `i == j`, you should let the calculation equal 0, instead of putting j to the 99 to exit the loop. Unless you do want to break out of the loop in which case you should use the `break` command instead.

A fun addition: this is a possible solution using list comprehension.

```
alldistance = [ 
    sum([getDifferenceCoord(locationList[i], locationList[j]) for j in range(0,99)]) 
    for i in range(0, 99)
]
```

Comment: You are right, thank you for your advice. I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" in the code you add.

Comment: What type does getDifferenceCoord(locationA, locationB) return?

Comment: function returns float value.

Comment: I can confirm that the code works for me, so it will probably be a conflict with your specific implementation. Could you show me the result of `print(getDifferenceCoord(locationList[0], locationList[1]))`?

Comment: 19.235384061671343

Comment: Ok, it turns out there was a typo, I missed a bracket. I mustn't have copied it over after correcting it on my local. Try that now.

Answer (score 1):

Try - >

```
import math
from itertools import combinations

for item in  combinations(locationList,2):
    print(f'distance for locations {item} = {math.dist(item[0], item[1])}')
```

You can use math.dist to evaluate the distance more cleanly -

```
import math
from itertools import combinations

result = [math.dist(item[0],item[1]) for item in  combinations(locationList,2)]
```